# send formData POST request with nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I want to send a post request that contain a form data, i want to do that from nodejs to another external api, i don't have the front-end to send the formData, so all i have a javascript object that has keys and values, so how can i do that?, when i tried sending a normal object, i didn't get the right api response, but when i sent it with a POSTMAN client, i got the correct response.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a correct result in Postman, it's interesting to use the **code generator** in the same tools to have the desired code :). The button "</>" is on the right bar of the screen.

Here is the code generated from the tool :

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('data', 'asldkfjalsdkjf');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://some-domain.com/formdata',
  headers: { 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

It's cool, isn't it?
One more thing, you have many options from NodeJS to C#, PHP.. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make a post request with nodejs? In order to do so, you can use the `axios` library and send the data in the following way.

```
const axios = require('axios');

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('x': 'some test data');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67709177',
  data: formData,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

You can install axios using this command.

```
npm i axios
```

Comment: the problem is, how do get the "x: 'some test data'" to be of type FormData, because apparently when i sent a normal object, the api responsded with "please provide a formData", and when i used postman to do that, it worked

Comment: You need to create a FormData object for that. 
I've updated my answer.

Comment: Bro you have syntax error